# Traveling back to US and Passport expiring soon

Tags: usa, us-residents, venezuelan-citizens

I am a Venezuelan citizen and an American legal resident (green card holder). I am currently in Vancouver, Canada and my passport expires on the 23rd of November 2016. Can I travel back to the US on the 13th of November? Currently, I plan to go back on the 5th of November.

Answer (score 5):

[You can enter the US *solely* on your Permanent Resident card.](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents) Only it needs to be valid and not expired. It doesn't matter when your passport expires.

From the CBP:

> U.S. LPRs *do not* need a passport to enter the United States as per ([8 CFR 211.1(a)](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title8-vol1/pdf/CFR-2011-title8-vol1-part211.pdf)), however, they may need a passport to enter another country.

When you return to the US, you should contact a Venezuela embassy or consulate to renew your passport, as you will probably need it to travel elsewhere in the world.

Comment: Thanks! I have already started the pertaining steps, first for an appointment which the Government of Venezuela requires for its citizens to do when one is renovation a passport, appointment that I am still waiting for since July in order for me to attend the Venezuelan Consulate to begin the application for a new passport. Due to the grave situation in Venezuela everything takes a LOT of time to do specially with anything tied to Government, because all passport issues are done in Venezuela. So yes, the renewal situation is on its way. Thanks again for the info!

Comment: @Guest You could be waiting a long while for that passport, then. You may also consider obtaining a [US Re-Entry Permit](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/B5en.pdf), which you can use instead of a passport to obtain visas and travel, until you are able to obtain US citizenship.

Answer (score 4):

The upcoming expiration of your Venezuelan passport will not affect your re-entry into the US, whether you return on the 5th or on the 23rd of November.

Lawful Permanent Residents of the U.S. must present a valid, unexpired Permanent Resident Card (Green Card, Form I-551). While not required, it's a good idea to carry your identity document (passport, foreign national ID card, or US driver's license). You'll want to renew your passport for future travel, as the green card may not give you admission to other countries, as you know.

While they may not apply to you, if you've taken a brief trip to Canada, there are other conditions which can affect an LPR: a reentry permit can be required if one is out of the country for more than a year or, if gone for 2 or more years, a returning resident visa would be needed.

Comment: LPRs do not need any identity documents in addition to their green cards. Also, Canada *does* accept the green card for entry, so it's not universally true that it doesn't allow admission to other countries.

Comment: That's what I thought, but [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident#reenter) is now saying: _When arriving at a port of entry, a U.S. Customs and Border Protection Officer will review your permanent resident card and any other identity documents you present, such as a passport, foreign national I.D. card or U.S. Driver’s License, and determine if you can enter the United States._

Comment: Yes, they've been saying that for a while now. *Any* here means that the additional ID is optional. If you have it, you should presumably "present" it, but it's not necessary to have it

Comment: I have already started the pertaining steps, first for an appointment which the Government of Venezuela requires for its citizens to do when one is renovation a passport, appointment that I am still waiting for since July in order for me to attend the Venezuelan Consulate to begin the application for a new passport. Due to the grave situation in Venezuela everything takes a LOT of time to do specially with anything tied to Government, because all passport issues are done in Venezuela. So yes, the renewal situation is on its way. Thanks again for the info

Comment: USCIS are _not_ the department that staffs the border, and so that's not authoritative. (They deal with people who are already here.) CBP is who run the border, and their statement can be found in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but under the WHTI green cards do not qualify for air travel, so the green-card-only option is available only for land and sea travel.

Comment: @phoog The WHTI is [irrelevant](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative) for permanent residents traveling on their green card. And [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=VE&DE=US&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=US&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) will tell the airline that green card holders don't require any passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so it is. Some pages don't mention this; I obviously found such a page first.

Comment: @Guest so you don't actually require a passport to travel to Canada.

Comment: @phoog but they do always ask for it. But is good to know that I can travel back to the US on the 13th, still 10 days before my passport expires. Thanks so much for all the info!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks so much for all your info!!!

Comment: @Guest the fact that they ask for it doesn't imply that they would refuse you if you were to say "I don't have it."

Comment: @phoog that is good to know!